# "In the figure below" or "in the below figure"?

Tags: grammar, phrases, adjectives, above-below

I frequently encounter this in technical documents and I am wondering which one is correct.

> In the figure below

or

> In the below figure

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first example is correct, not the second.

*Below* is generally used as an adverb or preposition, not as an adjective. See, e.g., [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/below).

As such, it does not modify *figure*.

In the first example, it could be construed as either, based on what is implied.

As a preposition

> In the figure below [this spot] . . .

Or as an adverb

> In the figure [shown] below . . .

Comment: Thanks for answering, now I can prove to them they're wrong.

Comment: Or on the other hand, see [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/below), avoid it because the usage is rare and not without it's detractors, but don't tell someone they're wrong for doing what's attested for a century.

Comment: @JonHanna -  I understand that the construction is possible, if rare and historic (as is *prithee*). But the currently accepted usage does not support use as an adjective (and it sounds off to me). But I agree that *wrong* is a value judgment that is always subject to disagreement. I'm a lawyer. I can defend and justify almost anything. [Is that so wrong?](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/287876-i-just-want-to-be-loved-is-that-so-wrong)

Comment: It's not historic, it's late 19th Century to the current day, and growing in popularity. I don't think it's a good idea to use it, but I don't think it's a good idea to tell someone they're wrong if they do either, unless you're in a position to determine style-guides.

Answer (score 3):

They're both correct, and amount to the same thing, but the second use of *below* as an adjective is less common.

So uncommon in fact, that you can find native speakers complaining to lexicographers about it. That in itself may be a reason to avoid it, though it has nearly a century of attested use.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I've always known something is wrong with the second example I just don't have enough proof. :)

Comment: Hmm. Just found a use from 1889, earlier than M-W give as their first found.

Comment: Not so much wrong, as just not very usual. This sort of thing is best treated with the principle, "Be liberal in what you accept, and conservative in what you send", which is a saying from software engineering, but applies to other things too. In this case, don't use it yourself (so as not to upset those who hate it or think it wrong), but don't complain when others do use it.