# "In the Figure 1 (below)" or "in Figure 1 (below)"

Tags: british-english, articles

I have a stupid question about the use of the word "Figure".

Do we say "In Figure below" or "In the Figure below".

Thanks

Omer

Comment: If you are writing a document with figures in it, you should look and see what the convention is for the sort of document you are writing, i.e. what other authors for the same book publisher or journal do. For any question here you are expected to show that you have done some research yourself before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question in the title and the question in the body are different, so let's answer both.

> In the figure below

is correct. Omitting the article would be ungrammatical. Technically if there was more than one figure below you could say "in a figure below".

However if you are already specifying which figure you mean you do not need an article.

> In Figure 1

is correct and needs no article.  In *the* Figure 1 would be wrong.

Adding 'below' parenthetically does not change that.

> In Figure 1 (below)

is also correct.

Comment: In other words, you have two choices -- (1) all lower case, with article; (2) upper case, without article.

Comment: It's the figure _identified_ by a number which doesn't need an article.

Comment: @aparente001 No. The case is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Oh, right.  It would be lower case when there's no figure number.

Answer (score 0):

In English texts it is usual to say "In **the** figure below". Read almost any text book or instruction manual to find examples.
This question has been [asked before](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100807/in-the-figure-below-or-in-the-below-figure).

Comment: I checked if it was asked before but I don't think so. Well, it's about "The". When using Grammarly for example, they correct it for me by erasing the "The". That's why I'm lost about this.